# Spin-waiting for an atomic to become a certain value

Tags: c, assembly, stdatomic

I want to spin-wait for an atomic to become a certain value and then acquire the memory `memory_order_release`'d with the store.

I thought that with optimization

```
#include <stdatomic.h>

void wait_for_flag_to_become2(_Atomic unsigned char *xp)
{
    while(2!=atomic_load_explicit(xp,memory_order_acquire));
}
void wait_for_flag_to_become2_(_Atomic unsigned char *xp)
{
    while(2!=atomic_load_explicit(xp,memory_order_relaxed)){}
    atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_acquire);
}
```

would generate the same code and that it would resemble the latter function, but on platforms where the outputted assemblies differ, they don't.

Are the two functions above semantically equivalent and are the differences in the outputted assembly due to a simple failure to optimize, or are they in fact not semantically equivalent?

---

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/hNcf-i

power64-at12, gcc8:

```
wait_for_flag_to_become2:
        .quad   .L.wait_for_flag_to_become2,.TOC.@tocbase,0
.L.wait_for_flag_to_become2:
.L2:
        lbz 9,0(3)
        cmpw 7,9,9
        bne- 7,$+4
        isync
        rlwinm 9,9,0,0xff
        cmplwi 7,9,2
        bne 7,.L2
        blr
        .long 0
        .byte 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
wait_for_flag_to_become2_:
        .quad   .L.wait_for_flag_to_become2_,.TOC.@tocbase,0
.L.wait_for_flag_to_become2_:
.L6:
        lbz 9,0(3)
        cmplwi 7,9,2
        bne 7,.L6
        lwsync
        blr
        .long 0
        .byte 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

ARM64, gcc 8.2:

```
wait_for_flag_to_become2:
.L2:
        ldarb   w1, [x0]
        and     w1, w1, 255
        cmp     w1, 2
        bne     .L2
        ret
wait_for_flag_to_become2_:
.L5:
        ldrb    w1, [x0]
        and     w1, w1, 255
        cmp     w1, 2
        bne     .L5
        dmb     ishld
        ret
```

Comment: but `atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_acquire);` and generate additional instruction on weak-memory cpu platform. say `dmb` on arm. and you use of course `memory_order_acquire` fence. not `memory_order_release`

Comment: say on x86/x64 `atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_acquire);` do nothing, because load not reorder with other loads or store after it. but on arm - this is [`dmb     ishld`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0802b/CIHGHHIE.html) - *Data Memory Barrier operation that waits only for loads to complete, and only applies to the inner shareable domain*

Comment: I believe the are semantically different. My (unsupported by any quote) understanding is that standard-wise load with acquire is required to read the new value after it was updated (at least at some point), but relaxed load can give you cached value forever, without ever updating this cache.

Comment: @SergeyA http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.17.3p16 : "Implementations should make atomic stores visible to atomic loads within a reasonable amount of time." Call me crazy but forever doesn't seem like a reasonable amount of time to me. :D

Comment: @SergeyA: On a real implementation, a relaxed load can only be reordered as far as the out-of-order machinery in a CPU core, i.e. over hundreds of instructions, i.e. nanoseconds but not microseconds.  The C++ standard doesn't put a hard limit on it, but says that relaxed stores should become visible to other cores promptly.  Given that current compilers don't optimize atomics basically at all, relaxed load and store are basically `volatile` but with a guarantee of atomicity.  Normal hardware cache-coherency mechanisms (MESI) ensure prompt visibility.

Comment: @SergeyA "_to read the new value after it was updated_" After? What would that even *means*?